# How can I reduce this complex exponent expression to real expression?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, complex

How can I reduce this to real expression?

```
expr= 1.0000000000000002` - 
 0.001255648708575318` E^(-10.012605635948601` t) + 
 0.17959901255646785` E^(-0.8648909907775479` t) - \
(0.5891716819239463` - 
    0.5616835474433535` I) E^((-0.061418353303592355` - 
     0.06265925347379434` I) t) - (0.5891716819239463` + 
    0.5616835474433535` I) E^((-0.061418353303592355` + 
     0.06265925347379434` I) t);
```

It looks good when I plot it but I want to simplify to real expression.

```
Plot[expr, {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rationalize[expr, 0] // Im // ComplexExpand
```

> `0`.

It means that `expr` is real.

```
Rationalize[expr, 0] // Re// ComplexExpand
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem created by using machine numbers. These are seldom 100% accurate, they are most of the time an approximation. And if you have an expression like: x - Conjugate[x] it is possible that the imaginary part does not accurately cancel.

Here is an example:

```
x = 1.23456789012345678;
x - Conjugate[x]
(* 0.*10^-17 *)
```

But if you are sure that the result is real, you can safely take the real part using: Re.

If you want to avoid such problems, you may use rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The last two terms can be simplified to real as follows
FullSimplify[-(c - d I) E^((a + b I) t) - (c + d I) E^((a - b I) t)==-2 E^(a t) (c Cos[b t] + d Sin[b t])]/.

```
1. - 0.00125565 E^(-10.0126 t) + 0.179599 E^(-0.864891 t)-2 E^(a t) (c Cos[b t] + d Sin[b t])
/.{a -> -0.061418353303592355`, b -> -0.06265925347379434`, c -> 0.5891716819239463`, d -> 0.5616835474433535`}

(*1. - 0.00125565 E^(-10.0126 t) + 0.179599 E^(-0.864891 t) - 
 2 E^(-0.0614184 t) (0.589172 Cos[0.0626593 t] - 
    0.561684 Sin[0.0626593 t])*)
```

Or in one line without doing the algebra...

```
expr // ComplexExpand // Simplify // Chop // FullSimplify
```

Chop gets rid of the 0`*I leftovers.